# Quartz doesn't start jobs sometimes

Tags: scala, quartz-scheduler

I use quartz in scala to schedule some jobs. The problem is the 20% times I start an application jobs are not properly started and the output is like this fragment:

```
 0:21:24.001 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8] DEBUG org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Calling execute on job group.Client:17;Lb:10
10:21:24.003 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4] DEBUG org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Calling execute on job group.Client:17;Lb:13
10:21:24.002 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7] DEBUG org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Calling execute on job group.Client:17;Lb:12
10:21:24.001 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] DEBUG org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Calling execute on job group.Client:17;Lb:11
10:21:24.004 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG o.q.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory - Producing instance of Job 'group.Client:17;Lb:15', class=pl.soi.sep.RunScripsAndUpdateLeaderboards
10:21:24.004 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] DEBUG org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Calling execute on job group.Client:17;Lb:15
10:21:24.005 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG o.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread - batch acquisition of 1 triggers
10:21:24.005 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG o.q.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory - Producing instance of Job 'group.Client:17;Lb:2', class=pl.soi.sep.RunScripsAndUpdateLeaderboards
10:21:24.005 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] DEBUG org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Calling execute on job group.Client:17;Lb:2
10:21:24.005 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG o.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread - batch acquisition of 1 triggers
10:21:24.006 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG o.q.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory - Producing instance of Job 'group.Client:17;Lb:20', class=pl.soi.sep.RunScripsAndUpdateLeaderboards
10:21:24.006 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5] DEBUG org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Calling execute on job group.Client:17;Lb:20
10:21:24.013 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG o.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread - batch acquisition of 1 triggers
```

As you see the jobs are said to be started but the aren't. I just have to restart the app to make it work again. Do you know what can be the problem?